# Why Am I Getting "Target Element Missing" Error?

Tags: stimulusjs

I'm getting an error in my Rails 6 app because it can't find my data-target, but I don't understand why.

The error in Chrome’s console:

```
Uncaught Error: Missing target element "channel.messages"
```

My view:

```
<div class="col-sm-10" data-controller="channel" data-channel-id="<%= @channel.id %>">
  <!-- Chat messages -->
  <div class="pr-6 py-4 flex-1">
    <div data-target="channel.messages">
      <%= render @channel.messages %>
    </div>
        <div class="pb-6 pr-4 flex-none">
          <div class="flex rounded-lg border-2 border-grey overflow-hidden">
            <span class="text-3xl text-grey border-r-2 border-grey p-2">
              <svg class="fill-current h-6 w-6 block" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M16 10c0 .553-.048 1-.601 1H11v4.399c0 .552-.447.601-1 .601-.553 0-1-.049-1-.601V11H4.601C4.049 11 4 10.553 4 10c0-.553.049-1 .601-1H9V4.601C9 4.048 9.447 4 10 4c.553 0 1 .048 1 .601V9h4.399c.553 0 .601.447.601 1z"/></svg>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="w-full px-4" placeholder="Message <%= @other_user.name %>" />
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= form_with model: [@channel, Message.new], data: { action: "ajax:success->channel#clearMessage" } do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :body, class: "form-control", data: { target: "channel.newMessage" } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

_messages partial:

```
<div>
  <div class="font-weight-bold"><%= message.user.name %></div>
  <div><%= message.body %></div>
</div>
```

my controller:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"
import consumer from "channels/consumer"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "messages", "newMessage" ]

  connect() {
    this.subscription = consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: "MessageChannel", id: this.data.get("id") }, {
      connected: this._connected.bind(this),
      disconnected: this._disconnected.bind(this),
      received: this._received.bind(this)
    })
  }

  disconnect() {
    consumer.subscriptions.remove(this.subscription)
  }

  _connected() {
  }

  _disconnected() {
  }

  _received(data) {
    if (data.message) {
      this.messagesTarget.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data.message)
    }
  }

  clearMessage(event) {
    this.newMessageTarget.value = ''
  }
}
```

When I inspect the HTML, it shows:

```
<div data-target="channel.messages">
```

Comment: It seems ok. Maybe you have multiple `data-controller="channel"` in your HTML?

Comment: @nathanvda that was it! if you post the answer, i will select it. thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code shown seems perfectly fine. The only thing I can think of, causing this behaviour, is if you have multiple `data-controller="channel"` in your HTML.

Comment: Why would that be an issue though?? Doesn't it support overlapping controllers?

Comment: My idea was that there was another div with the same controller, but where the target is missing.

Comment: Is this truly correct?  There are lots occasions where you would the same controller (a date input for example) over and over on a page.

Comment: You misunderstood: if there is a second div with `data-controller="channel"` but where the target is missing (aka incomplete), this would cause a javascript error, and the OP was only looking at the "correct" div (and did not look any further).

Answer (score 2):

The issue with my code was that the data-controller had to be in the parent element.

Initially it was located inside the form and it wasn't working properly. After I moved the data-controller inside the parent tag  everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the data-target attribut. You need to use:

```
data-channel-target
```

The definiion shows this structure:

data-yourcontroller-target

Comment: It dependes which Stimulus version is used. `data-yourcontroller-target="target_name"` is for Stimulus 2. Older (and IMHO still supported) version is `data-target="yourcontroller.target_name"`